# Robot standard libraries non accessible error

Tags: robotframework

I have installed java jdk 1.8v and robot framework 7.0v. Upon creating test suite, revalidating error popped up and robot standard libraries appeared with non-accessible error.

[image: Error message]

Is there anything to do with build path? If so, please provide the instructions.

Comment: you should remove old entries from the Run/Debug configurations.

Comment: I've just installed RED application and started with my very 1st test suite. So, there's nothing in run/debug configurations tab.

Comment: Changed the RF version to 3.2.2 from 7.0 and now it's absolutely working fine